# Polycom SoundPoint IP 4000 won't power on. How to isolate power supply?

Tags: asterisk, voip, sip, polycom

I have a Polycom SoundPoint IP 4000 SIP conference phone that has sat unused in a box for a number of years.

Today, I pulled it out of the box and powered it on with the conference power supply only to find that the speaker clicks, the red LEDs blink intermittently and the display shows a series of black lines as if there is a problem powering the unit.

My question is, how can I isolate the power supply? I've replaced all cables with the exception of the wall transformer and the power supply itself.

Can I power this device over standard POE, for example, to see if the power supply has gone south or if it's the entire unit?

I tried powering it with the power supply from an IP 601 and it didn't respond at all.

Thanks in advance for any advice on narrowing down which part(s) have failed here.

Answer (score 2):

A Polycom SoundPoint IP 4000 SIP can be powered using ether power-adapter or a standard POE connection.
The VVX 601 phone should use the same power supply as the 4000 phone, as most more recent phones now use the same power adapter. There should be a a power rated printed on the bottom of both the IP4000 and the VVX601.

The much older IP 601 used a different POE power injector, which is not capable with their newer phones.

Answer (score 0):

the above poster has got that wrong, the Polycom IP4000 audio conf phone needs a special TRIANGLE -  that sits between the phone and the PSU

Wikipedia suggests Polycom uses "PowerDsine Power over LAN". External reference shows a 3Com device (earlier mentions 3Com along with Polycom regarding Dsine) with V+ on pin 7 and V- on pin 8. Grab a multimeter, figure out the voltages, find a standard PoE injector that can supply those, and crimp your own "crossover" cable with the wires in the right places on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubiquiti UBI-POE-24-1 ( or the model GP-B240-100) have passive DC+ on pins 4,5  and DC- on pins 7,8

so you can use those older PoE's from Ubiquiti instead of the Polycom proprietary POE Triangle, but you will have to make up your own ethernet cable for it to work, as Polycom did not follow any PoE standards way back in late 2000

Standard     T568B Wiring     Polycom
Pin 4 DC+   Blue        to    Pin 1
Pin 7 DC-   White/Brown to    Pin 2 
Pin 1 TX+  White/Orange to    Pin 3
Pin 5    White / Blue        Not used 
Pin 8     Brown              Not Used 
Pin 2 TX-   Orange      to    Pin 6
Pin 3 RX+   White/Green to    Pin 7
Pin 6 RX-    Green      to    Pin 8